# Incorrect webjar version is being downloaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, spring-boot, bower, webjars

We have configured AngularJS application with spring boot using gradle. For downloading libraries, webjars are being used.
Incase of jquery, we have defined version as 3.2.1. But, when the gradle is built, jquery version 3.3.1 gets downloaded.

```
   compile group: 'org.webjars.bower', name: 'jquery' , version:'3.2.1'
```

[Screenshot of libraries downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhw0X.png)

As the index.html looks for `<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>` which is not available, it does not load bootstrap libraries as well.

But if we use `compile 'org.webjars:jquery:3.0.0'` instead of org.webjars.bower, it does not downloads the latest library, just the version specified.

It this behavior because of bower? Or is there any other configuration to be done in gradle?

Comment: You are probably using other webjar dependencies, which have a dependency on the newer version of jquery.

Comment: Yes i am using webjar dependency. But how does is points to latest version despite specifying the version?

Comment: Ordering in your build (sometimes) matters. Use `gradle dependencies` to check the dependencies and which versions will be used.

Comment: Can confirm that. Happened to me, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webjars-locator can be used to manage dependencies